# Problem reading excel with last version of Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, import

Well, I recently bought a new computer and installed Spyder as well as Python, and updated the libraries up-to-date using pip. Everything works well except for Pandas when I try to import an excel file.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "sample_sheet.xlsx"    
data = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

And this is the error I get

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

I have already installed xlrd as well as openpyxl with pip, and when trying to install it again it shows the following message

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)
```

I am not the only one with this error, a friend of mine has it too. Has anyone came up with a solution? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: try: `data = pd.read_excel(filename,engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: Already tried that, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Just copy xlrd and openpypl files (or your complete site-packages folder, if you want) from Python folder into your user appdata, to the path where python is installed.

In your case, copy all content from C:\users\lucas\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages to C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages or C:\Python39, depending on where you have installed Python